# Action mapping in struts

Tags: mapping, struts, action

I found in a struts project this action mapping:

```
<action name="action" class="MyClass" method="add">
<result name="success">/jsp/test.jsp</result>
</action>
```

And in MyClass there is no method name ="add" but there is a method "onAdd"
I wanna know if struts know the name of the method in this case or its an error ?
because I found this in much actionmapping in this project;

Thanks for your help;

Comment: Seems like it would be pretty easy to test.

Comment: yeah I know; but I thaught is there a configuration in this project for that struts make a mapping between "add" and "onAdd";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Server will throw exception there is no method MyClass.add().
For more details you can look struts2 documentation [Action Method](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.1.x/docs/action-configuration.html#ActionConfiguration-ActionMethods)

Answer (score 0):

Because when you are mapping action into the staruts.xml then you have to specify the particular class and method and if you are not specifying that method then by Default it will call Execute() method. so now try this and that will call the particular class.

```
<action name="actionname" class="package.class" method="methodname">
<result name="success">/folder/xyz.jsp</result>
</action>
```

that way it will work.